# "Possible Spam"-banner shown twice

Tags: bug, review-queues

I just came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23384256). Somehow the banner (*Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully*) is shown not only above the post to review (where it belongs) but also above the question which is not up for review. This seems like a bug to me.

[image]

Comment: A post is a single question or answer. So the first banner is for that specific answer and the second banner is for the question.

Comment: @Stijn Why is there a banner above the question tho? To me this seems like the question was also identified as spam which is clearly not the case.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's an indication that this review task is an audit. And looking at the review, it says exactly that :) *"Review audit passed 17 mins ago"*

Comment: @Stijn What's bothering me is that the review is not about the question it's about one of the answers - is the second banner just there for confusion?

Comment: I suppose. The answer isn't spam either. Review audits regularly show you strange things.

Comment: I imagine that the banner is there because sometimes questions are longer, and you can't see the top of the answer when you scrolled down to the end of the question. For shorter questions, you see header and footer banners at the same time. No biggie.